# Single select options binding with jQuery validation is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, knockout.js

I am binding a list of objects to a `select` using knockout. Object Class can have any number of properties

```html
<select id="TheProperty_City" 
        name="TheProperty_City" 
        class="required" 
        data-bind="options: cityList, 
                   optionsText: 'Name',  
                   value: selectedCity, 
                   optionsCaption: '--select the city--'" />
```

This works perfectly fine and I can use `viewModel.selectedCity().Name` or `viewModel.selectedCity().Value` for loading child elements.

My issue is with jQuery validation. If I leave the statement as above, jQuery does not reset the error even after selection.

I fixed it with by specifying the `optionsValue` in the bind, but then the `selectedCity` returns the scalar value and not the entire object. Any idea how to preserve the object behavior or do the validation differently?

```html
 <select id="TheProperty_City" 
         name="TheProperty_City" 
         class="required" 
         data-bind="options: cityList, 
                    optionsText: 'Name',  
                    optionsValue: 'Value', //added the optionsValue
                    value: selectedCity, 
                    optionsCaption: '--select the city--'" />
```

The error stays there when `optionsValue` is not specified:

[image: Without the OptionsValue]

Here's my Object Watch on `selectedCity`:

[image: viewModel.selectedCity() in watch returns an object]

Here's an Object Watch on `selectedCity` when `optionsValue` is specified:

[image: With OptionsValue]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that when dealing with objects as the value, the `option` elements have their value set to "".  The jQuery validation fails because of this.  You could write a binding or wrapper binding to the `options` binding that goes through and just sets them to a value, but I don't think that it is preferable to go that route.

A decent option is to store the value and use a dependentObservable to represent the currently selected object.

It would be like:

```
var viewModel = {
    cityList: [{ Name: "Madison", Value: "MSN" }, { Name: "Milwaukee", Value: "MKE" }, { Name: "Green Bay", Value: "GRB" }],
    selectedCityValue: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.selectedCity = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var value = this.selectedCityValue();
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.cityList, function(city) {
       return city.Value === value; 
    });
}, viewModel);
```

With a binding like:

```
<select id="TheProperty_City" name="TheProperty_City" class="required" 
    data-bind="options: cityList, 
    optionsText: 'Name', 
    optionsValue: 'Value',
    value: selectedCityValue, 
    optionsCaption: '--select the city--'" />
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EgCM3/

Comment: Thanks, thats what I have in place as a workaround but its tedious to do it for all dropdowns. My knockoutjs script is growing fast and I am wondering is it worth the effort as you lose the mvc Html control helpers, server ViewModel data annotations and inbuilt validation support. Ofcourse databinding is great. Anyway, I will make this as an answer to help other searchers.

Comment: How would you implement a custom binding to fix this?

Comment: I had same issue and solved in the same way as RP Niemeyer described. Still wonder how to make it nicer, cause as Jason wrote in't unreadable for large viewmodels.

Comment: Did anyone ever come up with a binding solution for this, this resolution does work but becomes very unmanageable in a medium to large viewmodel.

Answer (score 6):

Quite neat solution would be to add **optionsAfrerRender** parameter to options binding. Assuming that in 'selectedCity' object there is a field 'cityId' you could assign it to an option value. Please check the following solution based on your example:

```
 <select id="TheProperty_City" 
    name="TheProperty_City" 
    class="required" 
    data-bind="options: cityList, 
               optionsText: 'Name',
               value: selectedCity,
               optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) 
                                        { option.value = item.cityId; }
               optionsCaption: '--select the city--'" />
```

Using this approach you will get working both knockout options binding and jquery validation.

Comment: This works really well to get around weirdness when integrating with Bootstrap validators.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer works with one caveat. The first select value bound ("--select the city--") will be undefined causing an error.

If you modify the code to handle this it will work.

```
<select id="TheProperty_City" 
name="TheProperty_City" 
class="required" 
data-bind="options: cityList, 
           optionsText: 'Name',
           value: selectedCity,
           optionsAfterRender: setOptionValue
           optionsCaption: '--select the city--'" />
```

Note: I've stripped out everything from the ViewModel except for the setOptionValue method for brevity.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vm = {
    setOptionValue: function(option, item) {
        if (item === undefined) {
            option.value = "";
        } else {
            option.value = item.id;
        }
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Taking this one step further: in `setOptionValue` func, pass in the property name as a 3rd param (`propId`), and then do `option.value = item[propId]`. This can now be used for any dropdown with different model bindings.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Robert's answer, we can make the helper function work for every dropdown in the view model no matter the context data-binding by allowing the user to pass in a string for the right property:

**JS**

```
self.setOptionValue = function(propId) {
    return function (option, item) {
        if (item === undefined) {
            option.value = "";
        } else {
            option.value = item[propId];
        }
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="custom-dropdown" data-bind="options: cityList, 
        optionsAfterRender: setOptionValue('AppointmentTypeId'), value: selectedCityObj, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" data-validation="required"></select>
```