# Knockout Select Options Binding & jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting Knockout select options binding & jQuery required validation to work. From what I understand, knockout sends its value back to jQuery validation as an empty string "". I have read a few awnsers to my issue such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743786/knockoutjs-single-select-options-binding-and-jquery-validation-not-working) suggesting to use a dependantObservable for each dropdown, but that becomes too cumbersome in a large viewModel for me. Has anyone figured out a way to get knockout select binding to work with jQuery validation an easier way? Perhaps with a custom binding attribute in knockout or some other workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To explain a little more, im using a regular select binindg to an observable array for a lookup on my form, that is a required selection. I want to use jQuery validation to make it a required selection but it seems there is an issue with the way knockout sends the selected value to jQuery validation. Thanks!

Comment: it would be interesting to see a demo of the problem, you got one you can show?

Comment: I will write up a demo in fiddle and post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didnt have a chance to write up the fiddle, I did find a solution to the issue as shown here [Single select options binding with jQuery validation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743786/knockoutjs-single-select-options-binding-and-jquery-validation-not-working)

Since knockout isn't bringing back a value to jquery validation, its just returning an empty string, the workaround I chose was to continue to use jQuery validation and just bind to the Id field instead of the FK property directly and set the optionsValue to the Id field. For example,

```
<select name="creditRating" data-bind="options: $root.creditRatings, optionsText: 'creditRatingText', value: creditRatingId, optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```