# jQuery Validate required rule deems value empty, even though value is selected

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

Is there a way to bind a `<select>` element to an array of **objects** (e.g. `[ { foo: 5, bar: 10 }, ... ]`, so that jquery validate would deem it as selected?

Here is the issue, if `optionsValue` is not specified - then `<option>` elements will have no `value=` attribute set (Knockout will take care of updating `value` target). But from the jQuery Validate perspective means the `<select>` selected value (`$(element).val()`)is `""`.

Is there a way to handle this without custom jQuery Validate rules?

Comment: How do you mean *"bind a `<select>` to an array of objects"*? Can you show us some code? What's the big deal about writing a custom method/rule?  However if `$(element).val()` is always empty, then I don't know what you're going to do.

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6743786/594235

Comment: Why not have `optionsValue` specified? That is the value of the select.

Answer (score 0):

If `$(element).val()` is always empty, then even a custom rule/method is not going to work.

However, there is a workaround for situations where people want to validate an element that cannot be validated directly for whatever reason.  You would use a hidden `input` element to store a value and force validation on this hidden element instead.

Generically...

1. Enable validation of hidden fields by manipulating [the `ignore` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore).  Setting it to `[]` will tell it to ignore nothing.
2. Create a hidden field near the `<select>`.  `<input type="hidden" name="selectvalue" />`.  Note that your placement of this hidden element within your markup will affect the placement of the error message.  You can use this to your advantage.
3. Write a `change` handler and bind it to your `<select>` element.  So every time a selection is made, you would copy whatever relevant value into your hidden element.

   ```
   $('select').on('change', function() {
       // some code to copy the value into your hidden element
       $('[name="selectvalue"]').val(somevalue);
   });
   ```
4. Then force validation on the hidden element using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).  It would be the very last line within your `change` handler.

   ```
   $('select').on('change', function() {
       // some code to copy the value into your hidden element
       $('[name="selectvalue"]').val(somevalue);
       // force validation of the hidden element
       $('[name="selectvalue"]').valid();
   });
   ```
5. Since the error message will, by default, now appear just after the hidden element, you would use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place the message in a new location as needed.  You can do this conditionally to preserve the other element's default message placement.  You may not need to do this step depending on where you placed the hidden element.

   ```
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       if ($(element).is(':hidden')) {
           error.inserBefore(element); // whatever custom placement
       } else {
           error.insertAfter(element); // default placement
       }
   }
   ```
6. Don't forget to remove any validation rules from your `<select>` element since you're no longer validating it directly.

---

Otherwise, if you're simply validating the selection being made and not necessarily that it has a value, you could write a custom method that does only that... checks that a selection was made and ignores the empty value.

Without seeing more of your code or knowing more about your requirements, this is the best I can do for you.

Comment: I have a custom `isValid:` knockout binding that accepts a ko observable (a `ko.computed` most of the time), and bridges knockout and jq validation. I was hoping I can avoid adding `isValid: isValueSelected`.

Comment: @THX-1138, since my answer has nothing to do with `isValid` and `isValueSelected`, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: I was hoping ko has a config like "putSomeDummyDataInValueAttributeSoJQueryValidateRequiredRuleWillThinkValueHasBeenEntered: true"